# Browser does not prompt for client certificate when deployed on port 443

Tags: security, ssl, web, web-applications, client-certificates

I have run into a very strange situation.

I am developing a web application that requires client certificate authentication.

Whenever I deploy the application on the default HTTPS port 443 the browser does not prompt me for a client certificate, web application does not see any certificate being provided and thus flags the request as unauthorized.

#### Verified to work as expected

In the following situations the browser prompts for a client certificate to be attached and authentication works a expected.

- Deployed at https://localhost:8443/

  - Local computer with a self-signed SSL certificate that has been manually entrusted.
- Deployed at https://test.mydomain.com:8443/

  - Remote instance with valid SSL certificate provided from [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

The above scenario has also been verified to work as expected if I launch the web application with the sudo command to outrule that it causes the issue in the below scenario.

#### Situations when it does not work

- Deployed at https://localhost/
- Deployed at https://test.mydomain.com/

### Verified the following

- Everything is 100% intact in terms of configuration, the only change I apply is changing the port number from 8443 to 443.
- Verified on multiple browsers, Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Behavior is consistent for all browsers and in all scenarios.
- Cleared any caches, cookies, session variables and also inspected that no HTTP Authorization header is sent in the request.
- Verified that the exact same truststore is loaded by the web application in all scenarios.

**What could be triggering this behavior and what other tools/debug can I use to further understand what is going on?**

Comment: This seems to be related to my OS/Browser. Deployed a virtual machine and installed the client certificate and everything works as expected. However I am still stuck at the part understanding what mechanism in OS X or browser prevents to use the client certificate.

Comment: Problem is not related to the application itself but rather to the KeyChain of Mac OS X.